# Core 2.1 site on IIS not redirecting to SSL

Tags: https, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a site which works fine if I navigate on the https url, but on the http I get the IIS error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

This is obviously less than ideal.

The binding on IIS allows both http and https to be mapped to this site.

My Configure method in the startup.cs is:

```
if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error" );
            app.UseHsts( options => options.MaxAge( hours: 1 ).IncludeSubdomains() ); //todo when confident it is working, use 180 days
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects( "/Oops/C{0}" );

        app.UseXXssProtection( options => options.EnabledWithBlockMode() );
        app.UseXContentTypeOptions();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
```

So I have told it to use HttpsRedirection.

I have read that you must also set a port in the options, so my ConfigureSErvices method is:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection( options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.HttpsPort = 44373;
            }
            else
            {
                options.HttpsPort = 443;
            }
        } );

        services.AddHsts( options =>
        {
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours( 1 );
        } );
```

I am aware of the low value of HSTS timespan, but i read it was recommended to be short until you're happy it is all working (which clearly I am not..)

I have also included the MVC options of adding the REquireHttpsAttribute.

```
var skipHTTPS = Configuration.GetValue<bool>( "LocalTest:skipHTTPS" );
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>( options =>
        {
            if ( /*Environment.IsDevelopment() && */!skipHTTPS )
            {
                options.Filters.Add( new RequireHttpsAttribute() );
            }
        } );
```

My worry is that because I am getting the IIS error, it is not routing to core dotnet? I just don't have enough experience to know where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as expected, it was one of those ARGHHH moments.

The clue was

> because I am getting the IIS error, it is not routing to core dotnet?

in IIS I had "Require SSL" set to true in the IIS SSL Settings. This seemed a reasonable thing to do!

I guess it does make sense, IIS says it isn't ssl, so get lost. This is before .NET has a chance to intervene.

I hope this helps someone else and saves them the few hours I spent figuring out I don't need to "Require SSL", to require ssl!

Comment: Dude! Thank you. Saved me lots of time.